# Approximating an open set in measure with another open set whose boundary has zero measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a bounded open set $D\subseteq\mathbb R^n$. I'm wondering whether it is always possible to find another open set $A\subseteq D$ such that the boundary of $A$ has zero  Lebesgue measure and $D-A$ has zero Lebesgue measure.

Vitali's covering theorem says that we can always fill $D$ in measure with countably many disjoint closed balls, but I am unsure whether the countable union of these balls will have boundary with zero measure. Perhaps we can use finitely many of these balls to fill the measure up to $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Consider $n=1$.  Take a fat Cantor set (perfect, nowhere dense, positive measure) subset of $[0,1]$.  Take $D=(0,1)\setminus F$.  If $(c,d)$ is a component interval of $D$ and $A\subset D$ is an open set that  has the same measure as $D$ then $A$ is still dense in $(c,d)$.  So the boundary of $A$ is going to include the boundary of $D$ anyway.  If, instead you just want $A$ to *approximate* the measure of $D$ then you can arrange for a much simpler boundary.

Comment: Thank you. I see what you mean.